# На ваше место в шляпах

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение НА ВАШЕ МЕСТО В ШЛЯПАХ? спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

А в каком контексте употребляется это выражение? И есть ли там тире?

Если честно, то я первый раз его слышу. Могу только предположить... В словаре Ефремовой (помимо традиционных) у слова ШЛЯПА есть еще одно значение. ШЛЯПА - устар., название, дававшееся военными невоенному, штатскому человеку (пренебрежит).

Рискну предположить, что НА ВАШЕ МЕСТО - В ШЛЯПАХ... могли употреблять в виде "запугивания" военных, что, мол, не справитесь - штатских на ваше место возьмем. Больше пока ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: Аналогично. Не сталкивался. Поиск дает какие-то вхождения, но не точные и сомнительные.

Comment: Я тоже не слышала. Именно на это выражение только две ссылки - на этот вопрос и аналогичный вопрос на мэйле. И Яндекс,и Гугл дают одинаковый результат. Так есть ил выражение?

Comment: Выражение-то есть, но редчайшее... 
Ссылки не две,конечно, но, может, сотня-другая

https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B2+%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%22

Answer (score 1):

Тут бы разобраться, что оно значит, а уж откуда пошло... да мало ли.
"Без штанов, но в шляпе" - из той же, видать серии. Кто-то сказал - остальные подхватили.

Я так понимаю, что речь идет о должности, которая в представлении говорящего является или должна являться престижной или денежной. И на неё, типа, претендуют очередь "культурных", "которые в шляпах". как-то так. Выражение, понятно, достаточно новое, советского периода, вероятно - тридцатых годов или пятидесятых, когда шляпы (мужские) были не только модным атрибутом, но и некоторым символом успешности.